# Zeebus Puzzle #3

Tags: word, rebus

Another day, another rebus puzzle:

[image]

Hint #1:

> These objects serve a function in a card game and are typically designated using the specific terms depicted.

Comment: So, is QT's answer correct?

Comment: While it’s an appropriate answer, it’s not the intended solution to this puzzle.

Comment: I thought the same thing as @QuantumTwinkie and was sure that was the answer... but it isn't? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are

> wildcards.  The terms unscrambled are One Eyed Jacks, Deuce and Jokers, and Trey

which serve this purpose in the games

> draw poker, deuce wilder poker, jokers wild poker, and... three's wild poker?

Comment: Full disclosure: I just made up that last card game.  I've never heard of it in the wild.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. $(+1)$ :P

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Shuffled cards

Because

> You have nicknames of cards mixed up like "one eyed jack", "joker", "deuce", and "trey", which are all card names..

Comment: This is what I was thinking, too -- but I couldn't figure out the extra letters at the bottom beside the r13(wnpx)... _EDIT: ahhhh yes, now I see._  (+1)!

Comment: I think it says (bar-rlrq-wnpx)

Comment: This is an acceptable answer, but the answer I had in mind is more suitable...no pun intended ;)

Comment: rot13(Pbhyq vg or fbzrguvat yvxr "nyy gur pneqf ba gur gnoyr?") :) @zeethreepio

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie, rot13(Vg qrsvavgryl unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu cynlvat pneqf. Gurer'f n uvag va gur ireanphyne hfrq gb qrfpevor rnpu pneq.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Mix(ed) Poker?

This is because

> All the cards are nicknames of poker cards, mixed up.